# Weekly time series - changing x axis labels in r

Tags: r

I have a data set with 3 series, relating to weekly data.

example:

`data <- data.frame(col1 = c(1,2,3,4),col2 = c(5,4,8,6), col3 = c(9,2,3,6))`

I convert the data to a time series, indicating the data is weekly, starting the 10th week of 2018 and ending the 13th week of 2018:

```
data_ts <- as.ts(data, frequency = 52, start = c(2018,10), end = c(2018,13))
```

Using autoplot, I graph the time series, using facets = TRUE to separate each series:

```
autoplot(data_ts, facets = TRUE)
```

When I do this, the x-axis label just says "Time" and the tick marks are "1,2,3,4".

How do I get the x axis tick marks to represent the actual weeks?

When I try `xlim=as.Date(c("2018-03-05", "2018-03-26")`, I receive the following error:

> Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only

I would like to do this without writing out every single date since the data is actually much larger.

Comment: Where did you get the `autoplot` function from?

Comment: the `autoplot` function is from `ggplot2`